# How to define a type of object with keys of values of enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export const enum Enum1{
  key1='value1',
  key2='value2',
  key3='value3',
}

type ObjType = {
  [Key in keyof Enum1]: {
    some_object: number
  }
}

export const obj1:ObjType ={
  [Enum1.key1]:{some_object:123},
  [Enum1.key2]:{some_object:123},
  [Enum1.key3]:{some_object:123}
}
```

The above code produces an error:

> Error:(145, 3) TS2322: Type '{ [Enum1.key1]: { some_object: number; }; [Enum1.key2]: { some_object: number; }; [Enum1.key3]: { some_object: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Obj'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[Enum1.key1]' does not exist in type 'Obj'.

I would like to define a type (`ObjType`) that its keys are *all* the values of the `Enum1` enum.

How can I do that? If it's not possible, what is the correct way to enforce that `obj1` keys contains all `Enum1` values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close. You don't want `keyof Enum1`. `keyof Enum1` would be essentially `keyof` an enum value, and since this a string enum it would be `keyof string`. The `Enume1` type can be seen as a union of all enum memebers, so you can just use that:

```
export const enum Enum1{
  key1='value1',
  key2='value2',
  key3='value3',
}

type ObjType = {
  [Key in Enum1]: {
    some_object: number
  }
}

export const obj1:ObjType ={
  [Enum1.key1]:{some_object:123},
  [Enum1.key2]:{some_object:123},
  [Enum1.key3]:{some_object:123}
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Can you provide a link to any sort of documentation on the `in` keyword? (What can be on it's right and left side).

Comment: @StavAlfi on the left side you declare a type parameter, on the right sign you can have any type that can be used in an index or a union of such types. I don't have anything except the official handbook to offer